# purescript: change element inside SVG

Tags: html, svg, purescript, purescript-halogen

I have a SVG image like the following:

[image]

It is a simple SVG with a number in it. The SVG file looks something like this:

```
<svg ...>
  <g ...>
    <text id="my_text" ...>
      <tspan ...>
        6
      </tspan>
    </text>
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

I can load it in purescript Halogen:

```
import Halogen.HTML
import Halogen.Svg.Elements
import Halogen.Svg.Attributes

loadImage :: forall w i. HTML w i
loadImage = image [x 0.0, y 0.0, width 36.0, height 36.0, href "assets/my_image.svg"]
```

How can I programmatically change the number "6" in it?
Is there something like `document.getElementById("my_text")` ?
Can it be done with CSS?

Comment: There is certainly something like `document.getElementById`, but I don't think the browser will let you mutate an SVG that was loaded from a URL.

Comment: The Native JavaScript [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) I blogged about, can load an external SVG, inline it in the DOM and be accessed in the DOM

Comment: If you have the content of SVG as string, you can use the SVG parser defined in this repo https://github.com/getlistas/web/blob/master/src/Svg/Parser.purs to modify the inner element.